# javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException:

Tags: xml, exception, xslt

I m trying to compile an xsl using transformer factory, but it is constantly giving the exception :

XSL : `

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="no" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:element name="value">
        <xsl:text>-1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="time">
    <xsl:element name="time">
        <xsl:text>00:00:00</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Code :

```
String xslPath = "C:\\Users\\Vaibhav_Ajmera\\Desktop\\vaib\\";
String findxsl = "find_replace.xsl";
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource    (xslPath + findxsl));
```

I am constantly getting an exception : `

```
ERROR:  'Syntax error in ''.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates    (TransformerFactoryImpl.java:843)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer    (TransformerFactoryImpl.java:632)
    at com.bt.rtsm.processor.merger.MetricReset.transformXml(MetricReset.java:92)
    at com.bt.rtsm.processor.merger.MetricReset.metricReset(MetricReset.java:51)
    at com.bt.rtsm.processor.merger.MetricReset.main(MetricReset.java:194)
```

`

Can someone please help ? I guess something to do it xsl syntax but not able to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: THanks. Just now got it solved after reading thru couple of online articles.